# Application does not run on Nexus 7 but runs on other devices

Tags: android

I have made an application that runs on android phones and emulators pretty well, but it gives me an error when I run it on Nexus 7 :

Here is my logcat report :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.aks.mobilereagents/com.aks.mobilereagents.MobileReagentsAc
tivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:8
67)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.aks.mobilereagents.MobileReagentsActivity.onCreate(MobileReagentsActivit
y.java:153)
at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you expand on what IS the application, maybe ?

Comment: Thank you for your response but i found out my mistake.

Comment: You might consider expanding on both, then :p

Comment: You're getting `NullPointerException` in ine 153 of your `MobileReagentsActivity.java` - look into that file.  As to why it runs fine on other devices, there's no simple answer.  I had a problem with `NullPointer` in one of my apps specifically on Samsung Galaxy but it ran fine on all other phones.  Apparently, Samsung's variant of android did some initialisation in a different order from other devices.  Start by checking that line in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read your exceptions a bit more carefully. The error is almost certainly in your code (specifically, at `com.aks.mobilereagents.MobileReagentsActivity.onCreate(MobileReagentsActivit
y.java:153)`) and not the fault of the Nexus 7 itself.